# What is the difference between "Future.successful(None)" and "Future(None)"

Tags: scala, future

`Future.apply` starts an asynchronous computation whereas `Future.successful` creates an already completed Future with the specified result.

Now is `Future(None)` (`Future.apply(None)`) less efficient than `Future.successful(None)`?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`Future.apply(None)` creates asynchronous computation and executes it. It means that extra lambda object is created and extra task is scheduled (however trivial task).

`Future.successful(None)` just produces already completed future. It is more efficient.

Comment: Can you give same real world example for Future.successful? I can't understand why we need that, except then existing interface waiting Future[T] and we want to pass some Future with already known result?

Comment: @FatihDonmez That's essentially the use case, yes.  Why write two separate interfaces when you can just wrap the known values?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that `Future(None)` gives a big overhead, but still in it's default implementation each call to `apply` spawns a new task for a ForkJoin thread pool, whereas `Future.successful(None)` completes immediately. And each call to `map` or `flatMap` on the future creates a new task for the poll, which also gives some overhead, so you might want to take a look at `scalaz` Future/Task implementation which handles such details more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the accepted answer, but please check this link https://blog.colinbreck.com/future-successful-blocking-your-future-success/

`Future.successful` is not always more efficient, for some cases, it's better to use `Future` call.