# Get an object out of Akka future response

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm using Akka streams to rate limit the calls to an external rest application and use its result to enrich the data.
I can't get to map the `Future` `HttpResponse` to the data in the stream.

What I've tried so far

```
val result = src.throttle(5, 1.second).mapAsync(4)(person =>
        getExtraDetailsFor(person.id).map{
          response => person.withExtraDetails(**write code to get ExtraDetails from Future[HttpResponse] **)
        })

private def getExtraDetailsFor(id: String): Future[HttpResponse] = {
    // rest call
  }
```

Comment: You'll need to read the response and parse its content somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at it all wrong, coming from a non-streaming background the solution took a while to 'click'

```
val result = src.throttle(5, 1.second).mapAsync(5)(person =>
    getExtraDetailsFor(person.id) //Future[HttpResponse]
    .flatMap(response => response.entity.dataBytes.runFold(ByteString.empty)(_ ++ _).map(_.utf8String)) //Future[String]
    .flatMap(responseString => parseResponse(responseString)) //Future[Seq[Details]]
    .flatMap(details => Future(person.withDetails(details))))
  .runWith(Sink.seq)
```

Comment: If you change the last `flatMap` to `map`, you won’t need to wrap the result in `Future`. I’d also recommend looking into the details of `Future.successful` vs `Future.apply` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21466781/29470). If you use `map`, you won’t need either, though.

Comment: You might also be interested in Akka HTTP unmarshallers https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/unmarshalling.html